# How to say " I can go to all the other classes/courses" in Mandarin

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I am trying to say "I can go to all the other classes/courses" with respect to some classes/courses I cannot attend.
Especially the "all other classes" is troubling me: 我要能去都(?)课.
All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

(除了這兩門), 我能夠上其它所有的課. (Except these two), I can attend all other classes.

Answer (score 0):

you can say "所有其它的课程我都能够去上",